# What is the difference between scope website and websites?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I know Magento 2 have store, group, website, stores, groups and websites scopes type.

But my question when Magento use singular form and when it uses plural form.

Under `core_config_data` table sometimes it saves under website or sometime websites scope. How it decide this ?

[image: core_config_data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my question when Magento use singular form and when it uses plural form.

It's actually the otherway around: only the 'connector_configuration' which comes from the dotmailer module that uses `website`. So it's inconsistency. **You are supposed to use `websites`** or even better, when you're in working in PHP-Code use the constant `\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITES`

**Magento will always use the plural when querying the database!**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Config.php#L61

**Prove:**

`SELECT DISTINCT scope FROM core_config_data` will return:

- default
- stores
- website
- websites

`SELECT path FROM core_config_data WHERE scope = 'website'` will return:

- connector_configuration/catalog_sync/catalog_type
- connector_configuration/catalog_sync/catalog_visibility
- connector_configuration/transactional_data/order_statuses

Comment: That's different thing. Of course these plural scopes are existed so they must have some meaning and importance.

Comment: well if you don't believe me, give me the explanation what it's webiste instead of websites

Comment: It's not about I believe you or not. Here I'm trying to understand when to use website and where websites. If you look this file /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Option.php line 209. How will you comment it's also inconsistent ?

Comment: I get your question and provided further information on what to always use the plural.